# Replace multiple characters in one line Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a string which looks like this

```
var dragdropMatchResponseData = '2838[,]02841[:]2839[,]02838[:]2840[,]02840[:]2841[,]02839';
```

I want to replace the following

> 1: '[,]' into ':'
>
> 2: '[.]' into ','

I tried the following

```
console.log(dragdropMatchResponseData.replace({ '[,]': ':', '[:]': ',' }));
```

and

```
console.log(dragdropMatchResponseData.replace('[,]', ':').replace( '[:]', ','));
```

but nothing helped me

I want my end result to look like

```
'2838:02841,2839:02838,2840:02840,2841:02839';
```

I don't want to add replace in multiple times, I want to do this at one time,

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try regular expression

```
dragdropMatchResponseData.replace(/\[,\]/g, ':').replace(/\[:\]/g, ',')
```

The /g flag is to replace all the occurances within the string.

Answer (score 0):

Hey It can be easily achieved using `replace` function of JS

```js
var data = '2838[,]02841[:]2839[,]02838[:]2840[,]02840[:]2841[,]02839';
console.log(data.replace(/\[:]/g, ',').replace(/\[,]/g, ':'))
```